# Difference between event loop and thread per request model

Tags: spring, multithreading, tomcat, event-handling, httprequest

According to my research, I found out that in thread per request model, every request that comes spawns a new thread. Let's say I had 100 requests, I'd be having 100 threads running at once. Coming to event looped model (similar to spring webflux), we have a main thread that listens to the requests and delegates tasks to other threads. 
Now let's say we have 100 requests on event looped model. Here, the main thread will be free to listen but it will also have threads which will be waiting for response from DB or network, just like thread per request model. How does it make event looped model more scalable.

Comment: The event loop request model doesn't automatically make the entire application more scalable, ideally the DB and/or network access would also be asynchronous so you're not leaving threads idle waiting for operations to complete. You could argue that an event loop model allows you to have a fixed size thread pool for handling requests (e.g. 1000 requests could be handled by 10 threads instead of 1000 threads) which allows you to handle more concurrent connections without reaching the thread limit, but it wouldn't necessarily improve performance for the end user.

Comment: But again, what you said could be achieved by limiting the number of threads in tomcat properties. How is that any different?

Comment: That depends on how naively the process of accepting connections is implemented, if it is already using a thread pool to do that then I suppose it's not very different, but if it truly spawns a new thread per request then system resources will be consumed fairly quickly with many concurrent connections. Limiting the number of threads doesn't make DB and network access asynchronous though, you need to use a non-blocking library to do that, which would be necessary to truly scale the system.

Answer (score 3):

The key difference between Tomcat with Servlet API < 3.1 and servers as Netty powered with a Spring WebFlux is the way which IO and requests are processed : blocking or non-blocking.
[Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-new-framework) favors the second approach :

> Part of the answer is the need for a non-blocking web stack to handle
>   concurrency with a small number of threads and scale with fewer
>   hardware resources.

So to sum that, by using the Spring WebFlux API, much less threads will be created for as many as client http requests because a thread is not dedicated to a single client http request in this model.
The no-blocking approach means that : whatever the time to process a request, a thread that handles that will not block the application and keep the thread waited for a long time but will process another request during this time.

Take that example : your Rest or Mvc controller receives a request and the essential of the task to perform is requesting the database. With a blocking approach you create one thread by http request. With a no blocking approach, the thread delegates to the database, may serve other requests and that thread or another of the pool will go on the processing when the interaction with the database is finished.

Comment: But this can also be achieved by reduced max threads in application.properties file right?

Comment: Of course but it will also reduce the scalability of your server. With no blocking approach, your threads are better used : these don't block and wait that a task is finished.